# Why is copula entropy negative?

Tags: probability-distributions, independence, information-theory, entropy, copula

Most statistical measures are non-negative. Shannon entropy, $H(X)$, a statistical measure of disorder or uncertainty in probability distributions, is also non-negative, despite it having a negative sign at the front due to logarithm rules. (Probability values are non-negative too.)

The entropy of the copula density, $c(u,v)$, however, is negative, despite it having a negative sign at the front like Shannon entropy. The negative coefficient actually makes the positive value in the double integral negative in the end.
$$h(c(u,v)) = -\iint_{[0,1]^2} c(u,v) \log c(u,v) \, \mathrm{d}u \, \mathrm{d}v$$

Why is it negative? and what is the intuition then when we see, for example, a Gaussian copula density with an entropy of -3.5? Is it more uncertain than a copula entropy of -2.1?

From the opposite perspective, why isn't copula entropy positive, or wouldn't it be better if copula entropy were always positive?

> Ma, J. and Sun, Z. (2011), 'Mutual information is copula entropy',
> Tsinghua Science and Technology. 16(1), 51-54.

Comment: That's simply coming from different sign conventions. Your entropy formula above is the negative of some Shannon entropy.

Comment: Exactly, Shannon entropy is non-negative, but even though copula entropy also has a negative sign at the front of its formula, the negative sign causes the overall expression to actually *be* negative, unlike Shannon entropy. I wouldn't call logarithm rules sign conventions

Comment: I don't think so, because the negative of copula entropy, $$-h(c(u,v)) = - -\iint_{[0,1]^2} c(u,v) \log c(u,v) \, \mathrm{d}u \, \mathrm{d}v,$$ is equal to a non-negative measure called mutual information

Comment: ok, so now that we agree it is how it's shown, I'm here to try to gain an intuition behind the meaning of the quantity, and the values it spits out

Comment: I think I was wrong. Gonne revise tomorrow.

Comment: what's strange about both formulas having $(-)$ at the front, is that both, probability values (used in Shannon entropy), and copula uniform marginals (used in copula entropy) are non-negative. yet the result is one is always positive, while the latter is always negative. I'm wondering if it has something to do with copula entropy being in many ways a form of **joint entropy**, not Shannon entropy, given its two inputs $u$ and $v$, as opposed to univariate $x$. Plus, Shannon entropy is not **differential entropy**, which *can* be negative, but doesn't help much because it can be either $+/-$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Most statistical measures are non-negative.

Not true for differential entropies.

The "entropy of copula density" is negative just like the (differential) entropy of any density restricted to $[0,1]$ is negative.

Comment: yes I'm aware of that but talked about Shannon entropy on purpose instead. the problem with your answer is that differential entropy is not only negative. it can also be non-negative.  at least on a real number support $(\infty, \infty)$. copula entropy on the other hand is never non-negative. that's why I asked. personally, I have never seen differential *univariate* entropy for a support of $[0,1]$ so I find it hard to make the comparison to copula entropy, which is bivariate

Comment: For a bivariate density on $[0,1]^2$ , the maximum entropy corresponds to a uniform, and it's zero. Hence any density restricted to that will have non-positive differential entropy.

Comment: makes sense now. could you comment on the intuition on comparing two negative values of entropy for two different copulas like the example in the question? one being more or less negative than the other. which of the two copula density (dependence structure) would be considered more disordered/unpredictable: the one that's more or less negative? And is it statistically meaningful/intuitive to compare these negative values